# How to get all element of ArrayList of list Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

See below code, I want to get all element of ArrayList of list.

How possible by below code ?

```
for (k = 0; k < lists.size(); k++) {

    name = String.valueOf(list.get(k));
    number = String.valueOf(list.get(1));
    number = number.substring(2);
    Type = String.valueOf(list.get(2));
    Date = String.valueOf(list.get(3));
    Duration = String.valueOf(list.get(4));
    if (Type.equals("OUTGOING")) {
        calltype = String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE);
    } else if (Type.equals("MISSED")) {
               calltype = String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE);
           } else if (Type.equals("INCOMING")) {
                      calltype = String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE);
                      RestoreCallLogs(name, number, calltype, Date, Duration);
                   }
}
```

Comment: by iterating over the list.

Comment: What type of Object are you storing in your `list`?  How are you storing data into the `list`?

Comment: String Object store into list

Comment: Then you do not need `String.valueOf(list.get(k))`.

Comment: Either go for a for each loop or an iterator to iterate over the list...

Comment: consider to create a class that contains `name` `number` `type` `date` etc  and then store these Objects into the arrayList

Comment: You have `lists` and `list` in your code snippet. This is not likely to work.

Comment: oopppss sorry, but how to get element of inner arraylist

Comment: refer Java Docs API and javatpoint